# How can I get a cat to not meow after I stop playing with it?

Tags: cats, behavior, play

My cat loves to play fetch. We'll play for about 15 minutes before I end up doing something else. The moment I stop playing fetch my cat will continue to meow until I either play again, or until I hide the headband somewhere.

I don't want to keep having to hide the headband. Is there anyway I can train my cat to know when it's no longer play time, so it won't meow after I stop playing fetch?

I have a cat tree which he likes to play on, as well as other toys I don't need to get involved with, but he seems more interested in playing fetch. I just want the meowing to stop; I cant play fetch forever :(

Comment: Considering they meow for a variety of reasons, this is unlikely to be something you will get to ever stop completely.

Comment: Man, I feel your pain.  My female cat does this to me at all hours of the day.  We play fetch for a while and I will be in the middle of a text message and she won't stop meowing at me until I throw it again often times putting her front paws on my leg almost begging me and saying here I am throw it again pweez!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- For your play sessions, use a toy that really tires your cat out. For example, check out [da bird](http://www.petco.com/product/104943/Da-Bird-Feather-Teaser.aspx).
- At the end of the play session, introduce a toy that the cat can play with on its own. (For example, one of those balls with holes that you hide food inside.)
- I'm assuming that your cat is young. As cats get older, they tend to want shorter play sessions. So this is probably a self-correcting problem.